# python list of tuples to list of dictionary of nested lists

Tags: python, list, dictionary, tuples

I am trying to convert list of tuples (example z below) to z1. First 2 items in z can be same and so becomes common field in result's dictionary. Please below. My attempt is shown as well but it fails to group common element? Any help?

```
FROM:

z= [(53, 'example 2', 2, 'instagram', 'nyc'),
    (53, 'example 2', 5, 'instagram', 'detroit'),
    (53, 'example 2', 7, 'twitter', 'harlem'),
    (50, 'example 5', 8, 'twitter', 'harlem'),
    (27, 'example 6', None, None, None), 
   ]

TO:

z1=[
 {'id':        53,
  'name':      'example 2',
  'hashtags':  [ { 'tag_id': 2, 'platform': 'instagram', 'tagname': 'nyc' },
                 { 'tag_id': 5, 'platform': 'instagram', 'tagname': 'detroit' },
                 { 'tag_id': 7, 'platform': 'twitter',   'tagname': 'harlem' },
               ]
 },
 {'id':        50,
  'name':      'example 2',
  'hashtags':  [ { 'tag_id': 8, 'platform': 'twitter', 'tagname': 'harlem' },
               ]
 },
 {'id':        27,
  'name':      'example 6',
  'hashtags':  [ { 'tag_id': None, 'platform': None, 'tagname': None },
               ]
 },
]
```

My Attempt:

```
ld = []
for a, b, c, d, e in z:
    ld.append({ 'id':       a,
                'name':     b,
                'tag_id':   c,
                'hashtags': [{'platform': d, 'hashtag':  e}, ]
             })

print ld
```

Output:

```
[
 {'id':        53,
  'name':      'example 2',
  'hashtags':  [ { 'tag_id': 2, 'platform': 'instagram', 'tagname': 'nyc' }]
 },
 {'id':        53,
  'name':      'example 2',
  'hashtags':  [ { 'tag_id': 5, 'platform': 'instagram', 'tagname': 'detroit' }]
 },
 {'id':        53,
  'name':      'example 2',
  'hashtags':  [ { 'tag_id': 7, 'platform': 'twitter',   'tagname': 'harlem' },]
 },
 {'id':        50,
  'name':      'example 2',
  'hashtags':  [ { 'tag_id': 8, 'platform': 'twitter', 'tagname': 'harlem' },
               ]
 },
 {'id':        27,
  'name':      'example 6',
  'hashtags':  [ { 'tag_id': None, 'platform': None, 'tagname': None },
               ]
 },
]
```

Comment: Don't forget to mark the answer you end up using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you aren't looking to see if you've already added a dict with the given id to `ld` ("Have I already added the element with id 53 to the list?"). You need to check to see if you've already added it.

The first thing that comes to mind is storing previous ids in a dict mapping the to the index. This doesn't increase the runtime complexity.

```
ld = []
encountered_id_index = {}
for a, b, c, d, e in z:
    if a in encountered_id_index:
        index = encountered_id_index[a]
        ld_dict = ld[index]
        ld_dict['hashtags'].append({'platform': d, 'hashtag': e, 'tag_id': c})
    else:
        ld.append({ 'id': a,
                    'name': b,
                    'hashtags': [{'platform': d, 'hashtag': e, 'tag_id': c}]
        })
        index = len(ld) - 1
        encountered_id_index[a] = index
```

This is untested, but I think that should get the job done.

Unrelated, but I'd recommend changing the variable names in the for loop to something more meaningful. "id" instead of "a", "name" instead of "b", etc. I promise you that if you learn to properly name your variables now, you'll have fewer headaches in the future. It dramatically increases readability of your code.

Comment: 100% in agreement of not naming variables appropriately. Will change that.

Comment: A quick comment for OP extending Geoff's note about variable naming: the ability to troubleshoot by catching an exception and printing something like `"a is {a} and b is {b} and c is {c}".format(**locals())` is important enough reason to do: `"Exception during parsing of tag.\n id: {id}\n name: {name}\ntag_id : {tag_id}\n platform: {platform}\n tagname: {tagname}".format(**locals())`. Just be sure to lose any reference to `locals` before you ship the code to production -- you really shouldn't be relying on exposing your whole namespace in order to make code work!

Comment: @Geoff - accepted (with minor edit) your answer for it's simplicity, elegance and without using any other data structure. Though for learning, I will try out other answers as well. tx

Comment: I always mix up add and append in Python. Java is engrained in my head. I just removed some redundant code to make my solution slightly shorter.

Answer (score 1):

```
from collections import defaultdict, namedtuple

HashTag = namedtuple('HashTag', ['tag_id', 'platform', 'tag_name'])

class Entries:
    def __init__(self):
        self.entries = defaultdict(list)

    def add_entry(self, id, name, tag_id, platform, tag_name):
        key = (id, name)
        value = HashTag(tag_id, platform, tag_name)
        self.entries[key].append(value)

z1 = Entries()
for entry in z:
    z1.add_entry(*entry)
```

... the only thing I *don't* like about this is that you need to know both the id *and* name to look up an entry. If I were using this seriously, I would modify it to index entries only on id, then have a second dict linking name to id, then implement __ getitem __ such that it will do a lookup on either id or name.

Comment: should do `class Entries(object):` to follow new-style class definitions (allowing things like decorators and etc). Otherwise a superb answer I was struggling through myself.

Comment: @adsmith: for Python 2.x, yes; no longer necessary in Python 3.x